# Eclipse plugin: Self hosting work's but jar give unexpected behavior

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have finished developing a plugin for eclipse, along the way I have been using the self hosting feature of eclipse to test and debug my plugin.  However, after exporting the plugin and installing it into my own eclipse host, hardly anything works.

I have JavaFX UI's which wont appear anymore, file's cannot be read due to URI's not being hierarchical, and other parts working very strangely.

I came here to ask why does the plugin work on a self hosted eclipse application while when exported and installed on my current host does not work?

Could it be something to do with other plugins causing conflict ?

Does self-hosting work differently than installations of jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that your code is packed in to a jar. If you are trying to access files in your plug-in using things like `File` or `FileInputStream` or anything else that expects a file these will not work. There are specific Eclipse APIs you must use to access resources in plug-in jars (mainly `FileLocator`).

Another common mistake is not including everything that is required in the plug-in in the `build.properties` file. The plug-in jar only includes files listed in this file. When you test locally this requirement is not checked.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed to know.